# New database in SQL Server is getting created with tables from another database on the same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have SQL Server installed on my machine with a few databases in it. Now I am creating a new database on the same server: `Databases -> right click -> New database`.

When I open the database it is getting created with tables from another database on the same server! Did any one see this behavior/problem before? Any possible solution?

Comment: It is created based on model db. Normal behavior

Comment: yeah just create sample table in Model database the same will reflect in Newly created Database.New Database are replica of Model Databases and behaves like SnapShot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is completely normal. New databases are based on system model database which is template for them.

[Model database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> When a CREATE DATABASE statement is issued, the first part of the database is created by copying in the contents of the model database
>
> Is used as the template for all databases created on the instance of SQL Server. Modifications made to the model database, such as database size, collation, recovery model, and other database options, are applied to any databases created afterward.

Read also about other system databases and their usage [model/msdb/tempdb/model/resource](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178028%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: is there a way in which I can reset this model database. It looks like I places some tables in it unintentionally.

Comment: Find tables you don't want in newer database and `USE model GO DROP TABLE name`. It will affect only new databases you create after that.

Comment: Or you can restore model DB from backup if you have any

Answer (score 1):

New databases are created as a copy of the `model` system database.

By default, this database is empty, but there is nothing stopping a user with the proper permissions from adding tables or data to the that database.  Indeed, if you want to control how new databases are created such as default compatibility levels, default languages, default function, data types, etc. then you can do so by creating them in the `model` database.